# Can you change the name of the tables in a query in Access 2000 programatically?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query that retrieves information and saves information to a table. This structure was created for one table. I need to use the exactly same structure with same field names with 200 other tables. The form is link to this query. I Was thinking on creating a combo box where you can select the table that you want. Is it possible to change the name of the two tables ( Catalog Number Log and Engineering Schedule) of the Query. So it point to two diferent tables (catalog number Log 1 and Engineering Schedule 1) Programmatically?

Query

[image]

[image: Form on how to add Catalog Number to Table Catalog Number Log]

Comment: this indicates a bad data model. In a database it should NEVER be requiered to have more then one table with the same structure ... especially not 200! But to solve your problem: have a look into the online help under "QueryDef" object

Comment: If you need 200 identical tables with different names I would think your design is flawed. Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe you can add a column to the table to differentiate the data stored (if this is the reason you want different tables).

Comment: The problem is that there is a form link to a table as shown on the picture above. My boss want the entries to be in order. So if i have a cat number 5203-000000-001 and then I add a 5203-000000-002 they need to be in sequence. We have a new Product which has the catalog numbers 52xx , 53xx , 54xx , 55xx All of those together add 200 tables. How it would be possible to have all those catalog numbers on the same table but keeping a sequence . For example I cannot have 5403-000000-001 and then if I want to add a 5204-000000-002 it has to be after 5204-000000-001.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Form record source : `SELECT CatNo, OtherStuff FROM MyBigTable WHERE CatNo LIKE '5204*' ORDER BY CatNo` Better yet, split the CatNo over several fields.

Comment: I'm trying to do the fallowing but its giving me a Syntax Error. Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Sequence No,Catalog Number,PO Number,Assignee,Customer Name, Marketing Sales Mgr, Notes, Rating Information From Catalog Number Log 2 WHERE Catalog Number Like '34*' ORDER BY Sequence No" . Any Help would be great ! thanks

Comment: You must put square brackets around field names with spaces eg [Catalog Number], or better, get rid of the spaces before they drive you insane. Use the Query Design Window to build queries if you are unsure, then switch to SQL view to get the string.

Comment: as above mentioned. Make a backup, merge all tables together, use order by function to present the data in a sequence order. You may have 3 columns for your cat number [5xxx][xxxxxx][xxx]

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused...your screenshot appears to be a bound form which means it's linked to a single table.  Are there multiple forms, all identical, bound to different tables?

If you must have a multitude of forms and tables all replicating the same structure then I suggest building a form that lets the user select a table from a combobox. You can then use a command button control to open the respective form based on the selected item in the combobox.

This will require that you write some VBA to dynamically control what form is opened.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm Me.cboFormList.Value
End Sub
```

I'm nervous about continuing with the idea of 200+ identically structure tables just to you have data in contiguous order.  A redesign is really going to be needed soon.

Comment: As suggested in the comments above. I ended using only two tables. One for 34xx-xxxxxx-xxx and other for the 5xxx-xxxxxx-xxx catalog Numbers. I Use one form and then I would programmatically change the recordsource = Select Catno, OtherStuff from BIgtable where Catno Like '52*' order by Catno  as @Fionnuala suggested.